# Extract absolute path operation from SVG data value

Tags: regex, svg

I have the following d attribute for SVG but the question is about regular expression :

M772.333,347.86c0,2.284-1.652,4.14-3.689,4.14h-52.622c-2.038,0-3.69-1.854-3.69-4.14V296.139c0-2.286,15.652-1.14,17.69-1.14l-0.189-3h38.81c2.039,0-0.31,4.854-0.31,7.14L772.333,347.86z

I'm looking for a way to get the blocks that has capital and a series of number so the result array should be [M772.333,347.86, V296.139, L772.333,347.86]

The pattern [A-Z]?[0-9.,] gives capitals and the numbers next to it but as well as the numbers after lowercase letters. I'd like to get rid of the numbers after lowercase letters.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is get rid of the question mark: `[A-Z][0-9.,]+`.  In `[A-Z]?`, the question mark makes the letter optional; you don't want that.

Comment: Yes, your pattern is simpler therefore efficient and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: I have one more challenge for you. Could you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605969/in-actionscript-how-to-match-in-infinitive-structures-like-to-cross-out-off I feel like I'm close but still not there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question.

(?![0-9,-.])[A-Z]?[0-9.,]+ is the pattern that finds the required capital and number groups.